# Use org-ref to add citations in theorem titles

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, org-ref

I am experimenting with writing a manuscript in org-mode and wondering if this is something org-ref can do

In org-mode I have

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :options [Homeslice's Theorem]
#+BEGIN_theorem latex
blah blah                
+END_theorem
```

which produces the following correct TeX

```
\begin{theorem}[Homeslice's Theorem]
blah blah
\end{theorem}
```

I would like to add a citation to the theorem's title which I can do in TeX like

```
\begin{theorem}[(\cite{homeslice_bib_entry}) Homeslice's Theorem]
blah
\end{theorem}
```

But using org-ref to accomplish the same goal does not work

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :options [(cite:homeslice_bib_entry) Homeslice's Theorem]
#+BEGIN_theorem latex
blah blah                
+END_theorem
```

Is there a way to do this in org-mode using org-ref or should I use the TeX citation?

Comment: I think you have to use the tex citation. I don't think the attr_latex lines get expanded at all. The only alternative would be some kind of preprocessing to expand that before exporting to latex.